# How can I create even column with items in them left and right aligned

Tags: html, css

1) I'm creating a list of paragraphs(2 column count) that has item name and price in it. I want items to be left aligned and prices to be right aligned (trying to push the price span to the extreme right side of each paragraph tag).I

2)The columns are not aligning on top correctly. If you see there is a gap creating uneven column. How do I correct this?

[image]

```css
.mainDiv {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  width: 650px;
  background-color: green;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.thetag {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.leftAlign {
  text-align: left;
}

.rightAlign {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Bread:</span><span class= "rightAlign"> $3</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Butter: </span><span class= "rightAlign"> $5</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Milk: </span><span class= "rightAlign"> $3</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Pasta:</span><span class= "rightAlign"> $5</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Banana:</span><span class= "rightAlign"> $2</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Apple: </span><span class= "rightAlign"> $1</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Broccoli:</span><span class= "rightAlign"> $4</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Potato: </span><span class= "rightAlign"> $3</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Cucumber: </span><span class="rightAlign"> $4</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.mainDiv {
  column-count: 2;
  
    /* optional */
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 1em;
}

.mainDiv > p {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  break-inside: avoid;

    /* optional */
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #fff transparent #ddd;
    padding: 1em;
}

body {
  /* necessary on SO */
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <p><span>Bread:</span><span> $3</span></p>
  <p><span>Butter: </span><span> $5</span></p>
  <p><span>Milk: </span><span> $3</span></p>
  <p><span>Pasta:</span><span> $5</span></p>
  <p><span>Banana:</span><span> $2</span></p>
  <p><span>Apple: </span><span> $1</span></p>
  <p><span>Broccoli:</span><span> $4</span></p>
  <p><span>Potato: </span><span> $3</span></p>
  <p><span>Cucumber: </span><span> $4</span></p>
</div>
```

- used flexbox to align the prices
- fixed markup validation errors
- removed unnecessary classes
- removed hard-coded width. You can set a max-width using `max-width` on `.mainDiv` but you should still let it shrink on mobile devices

You could add this for very narrow devices (change `540px` to whatever makes sense in your case):

```
@media (max-width: 540px) {
  .mainDiv {
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

---

What fixes the vertical alignment problem:

- `margin-top: 0;` on first `<p>` element, overriding browser default `margin-top`
  (or `-webkit-margin-before`) on `<p>`s.
- `break-inside: avoid;` on each `<p>` (this avoids column breaks inside `<p>`s for the more general case, where `<p>`s could have more than one line).

What aligns the prices to right:

```
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommen turning your layout into `flexboxes`

By making `.mainDiv` a flex container, we can align the items in the wanted layout

```
.mainDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Then we turn `.thetag` items into flex containers so we can align the items and their prices

```
.thetag {
  width: 45%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

```css
.mainDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.thetag {
  width: 45%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.leftAlign {
  text-align: left;
}

.rightAlign {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Bread:</span><span class- "rightAlign"> $3</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Butter: </span><span class- "rightAlign"> $5</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Milk: </span><span class- "rightAlign"> $3</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Pasta:</span><span class- "rightAlign"> $5</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Banana:</span><span class- "rightAlign"> $2</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Apple: </span><span class- "rightAlign"> $1</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Broccoli:</span><span class- "rightAlign"> $4</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Potato: </span><span class- "rightAlign"> $3</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Cucumber: </span><span class- "rightAlign"> $4</span></p>
</div>
```

This next snippet doesnt mess with the order of the element, I still recommend using the first snippet.

```css
.mainDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 49%;
  height: 280px;
}

.thetag {
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.leftAlign {
  text-align: left;
}

.rightAlign {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Bread:</span><span class- "rightAlign"> $3</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Butter: </span><span class- "rightAlign"> $5</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Milk: </span><span class- "rightAlign"> $3</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Pasta:</span><span class- "rightAlign"> $5</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Banana:</span><span class- "rightAlign"> $2</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Apple: </span><span class- "rightAlign"> $1</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Broccoli:</span><span class- "rightAlign"> $4</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Potato: </span><span class- "rightAlign"> $3</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Cucumber: </span><span class- "rightAlign"> $4</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are changing the display order of elements and that was not part of the requirement. See position of `Butter` in your code and its position in OP's example. Why do it when it was not required?

Comment: Thank you @AndreiGheorghiu added a second snippet

Answer (score 1):

Remove the top margin from the paragraphs and float the price to the right.

```css
.mainDiv {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  width: 650px;
  background-color: green;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.thetag {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 0 1em
}

.leftAlign {
  text-align: left;
}

.rightAlign {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Bread:</span><span class="rightAlign"> $3</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Butter: </span><span class="rightAlign"> $5</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Milk: </span><span class="rightAlign"> $3</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Pasta:</span><span class="rightAlign"> $5</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Banana:</span><span class="rightAlign"> $2</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Apple: </span><span class="rightAlign"> $1</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Broccoli:</span><span class="rightAlign"> $4</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Potato: </span><span class="rightAlign"> $3</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Cucumber: </span><span class="rightAlign"> $4</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to add **`*{margin:0; padding:0;}`** on the top of your css file, so you don't see any unexpected spacing.

Now that will solve the issue, with some minor changes.

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
.mainDiv {

   -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2; 
  grid-gap:50px; /*equals to the difference between the sum of two elements minus the width of the parent: in your case (300+300)-650=50*/
  width:650px;
  background-color: green;
}

.thetag {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom:15px; // if you want some space between the items
}

.leftAlign {
  text-align: left;
}

.rightAlign {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Bread:</span><span class= "rightAlign"> $3</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Butter: </span><span class= "rightAlign"> $5</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Milk: </span><span class= "rightAlign"> $3</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Pasta:</span><span class= "rightAlign"> $5</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Banana:</span><span class= "rightAlign"> $2</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Apple: </span><span class= "rightAlign"> $1</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Broccoli:</span><span class= "rightAlign"> $4</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Potato: </span><span class= "rightAlign"> $3</span></p>
  <p class="thetag"><span class="leftAlign">Cucumber: </span><span class="rightAlign"> $4</span></p>
</div>
```